# How can I analyze how environmental conditions are related among different sites?

Tags: climate-change, temperature, correlation, natural-conditions, ndvi

I want to analyze how the environmental conditions along the migratory route of a bird are related to the environmental conditions found at the breeding ground (which it is at high latitudes and we assume the rate of change is faster than at the stopovers). The environmental conditions are the NDVI, temperature, growing degree days.

Is it enough with a simple correlation analysis or is there's another approach to make the analysis more robust?

thanks a lot in advance for your answers!

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to know what the caloric availability is along the way? Especially at breeding grounds?

Comment: Thanks for answering @Knob Scratcher, how does it work? what do I need to measure caloric availability? Is it the nitrogen peak content?

Comment: I believe he's alluding to food availability at different sites?  I added what are hopefully more useful questions on your newer question.